# Postgres: Tips on navigating with the command line

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to Postgres and the main problem I have now is that I don't have an overview of my server. If you use something like pgadmin3 it's easy to browse and to get a general idea of the structure of the database.

So looking for some general commands that could help me discover my database server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very basic commands:

Connect to database with client console

```
psql dbname
```

Dump db tables

```
\d
```

Dump a table schema

```
\d table
```

List table content

```
select * from table
```

General help

```
\?
```

Source/Further info: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Wow - that link refers to an extremely ancient version of PostgreSQL (although the psql commands haven't changed that much). The official manual might be a better place to learn about all psql commands: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: You're right the link is very old :) But still useful for the very basic commands. Thanks for pointing it out!